# How to extend a Content-Type Collection schema of a plugin

Tags: node.js, strapi

How can I extend a Content-Type collection schema of a plugin?, so I can add new columns.

as I want to add a column (named `croppedImageUrl` with `string` type) to the Collection [`File`](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/core/upload/server/content-types/file/schema.js) of the core plugin `upload` ([@strapi/plugin-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@strapi/plugin-upload)).

Answer (score 0):

`./src/index.js`:

```js
register({ strapi }) {
  strapi.contentType('plugin::upload.file').attributes = {
    ...strapi.contentType('plugin::upload.file').attributes,
    'workspace': {
      type: 'integer',
      configurable: false,
    },
    'user': {
      type: 'integer',
      configurable: false,
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.